# Determinant of barycenter of a hyperbolic-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinants

Let $A \in \operatorname{GL}(d, \mathbb{R})$ be a hyperbolic matrix. I want to show that $$\det((1-\alpha)A+\alpha\operatorname{Id})\geq 1,$$
where $0<\alpha<1$.

Attempt:

In $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$, a hyperbolic matrix $H$ can be written as
$$
H=P\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & 0 \\
0 & \lambda^{-1}
\end{array}\right] P^{-1},
$$
where $\lambda >1$. Therefore, one can calculate the above formula, but I have no idea how to prove it for $\operatorname{GL}(d, \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I thought that the eigenvalues of a hyperbolic matrix come in inverse pairs, $\lambda_1,1/\lambda_1,\lambda_2,1/\lambda_2,\ldots$, with $\lambda_i>1$, so then the identity follows, doesn't it?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you for you comment. You are right about eigenvalues, but I don’t get the prof. Could you please explain it?

Comment: well, the determinant equals $\prod_i f(\lambda_i)$, with $f(\lambda)=((1-\alpha)\lambda+\alpha)((1-\alpha)/\lambda+\alpha)> 1$ for $0<\alpha<1$ and $\lambda>1$; so the determinant is a product of numbers $>1$.